# C/C++ Control CPU Usage

Tags: c++, c, process, cpu

Hey guys anyone have any idea how to control cpu usage with simple c/c++ code?

In my case a while loop like this will consume cpu usage up to 95%,

```
while(true) {
    pow(2,10);
}
```

However I need to approximately monitor the usage between 0%~100% with a step like 5%.

I have tried to insert `usleep()` to the while loop however even with the minimum sleep time `usleep(1)` it only consume around 40% usage.

Any help is highly appreciated.

`Update:`
In additional, I am asking this question because I need to generate different CPU usage and then measure their corresponding power consumption. Thanks to David for pointing out that.

Comment: You need to describe the problem you're trying to solve before you can ask us for help implementing your chosen solution. "I need to approximately monitor the usage between 0%~100% with a step like 5%" because ....?

Comment: You can control how often you sleep as well as how long for.

Comment: Why down vote without giving any reason and suggestion? I don't think there is any duplicate question after search.

Comment: @David Schwartz I don't think given the reason why I am doing this do any help to this question. Anyway I need to generate different CPU usage and then measure their corresponding power consumption.

Comment: I downvoted because the question doesn't explain the problem you're trying to solve and that made it impossible to answer. Now that I know the problem you're trying to solve, I'll post an answer. (And if you update your question to include the problem, I'll change my downvote to an upvote.)

Comment: You could try something like `while(true){for(int i=0; i<RPT; i++) pow(2,10); usleep(1);}` to get your usage higher than 40%

Comment: This is a classic XY problem. The original premise of this question is fundamentally broken. There is very weak correlation between CPU usage and power consumption. It very much depends on what CPU is actually doing.

Comment: What operating system are you programming for? Also, please choose one of C and C++.

Comment: @FUZxxl  I am doing experiments on android wearable devices so it's linux.  And it really doesn't matter c or c++.

Comment: Why not measure MFLO/J rather than MFLOPS/W?

Comment: @user3386109 'the CPU is always doing something, even if all it's doing is sitting in the idle task' - not usually.  The 'idle task' is often a loop around a 'halt' instruction.  A halted CPU is typically does nothing at all, no fetches, no stores, no core/bus activity at all until an interrupt occurs.

Comment: @xl45 Then please pick one. Too often I've written a detailed C answer just to be told that it doesn't work because OP is working in C++ and my code isn't valid C++. Pick one and only one language to have your problem answered in.

Comment: @FUZxxl Actually I am working on user3386109's answer right now, on the other hand seems like you are going to provide a solution for exact this posted question which will also be helpful, then C would be good enough and thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check the wall time.
2. Do a significant number of computations.
3. See how much wall time has elapsed.
4. Compute how long you need to idle the CPU to get the usage percentage you want.
5. Sleep for that long.
6. Go to step 1.

Comment: Dynamic power is non-linear, so this solves the X (how to simulate the CPU load) but not the Y (how to find out the relationship between power and load). This is actually a efficiency VS performance(work/J at different frequency/voltage operating point) rather than performance VS power (MIPS/W).

Comment: @user3528438 The OP wasn't particularly cooperative in attempts to find out the real problem and provide a real solution. "*I don't think given the reason why I am doing this do any help to this question.*" So I decided to just understand what the OP was asking and answer it.

Comment: @user3528438 I see your point so how can I try to figure out the answer for Y problem? Can you explain what do you mean by MFLO/J or MFLOPS/W? Actually I've never heard about that.

Comment: @xl45 Performance is `work/time`. Power is `energy/time`. If you integrate `performance/power` over time you get `work/energy`, which is efficiency. Dynamic power is non-linear: the faster, the lower efficiency. You don't really care about power: you care about how much work you can do with the energy stored in the battery.